# Live search is not doing anything

Tags: php, ajax, search, mysqli, xmlhttprequest

I found one of basic php live search using ajax from youtube.com please see the sample at

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fS4Ys_ZEKw  that video speaking different language but i manager to type all of codes exactly of what you see from youtube.com , but different is the database name and table name, however, when I run is not showing anything to bring from mysql database even if pressed any key still not showing anything and not even errors. Can you see if i missed anything on this code compare to what you see from youtube!

search.php

```
<body>
<form name"form1" action="" method="post">
Enter name<input type="text" name="t1" onKeyUp="aa();"/><br />
<div id="dl"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function aa()
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","sea.php?nm="+document.forml.t1.value,false);    
xmlhttp.send(null);
document.getElementById("dl").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

sea.php

```
<?php 

$nm=$_GET("nm");

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "table");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


if ($result = $mysqli->query("select * FROM product WHERE product_name like('$nm%')")) 
echo"<table>";

    {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";?><img src="../<?php echo $row["screenshot"];?>" height="100" width="100" <?php echo "</td>" ; 
echo "<td>"; echo $row["product_name"]; echo "</td>";
echo "<tr>";    

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the response on `onreadystatechange`, do:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { //4:: request finished and response is ready
        document.getElementById("dl").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","sea.php?nm="+document.forml.t1.value);    
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: @andy true (last parameter of xmlhttp.open() ) makes the request asynchronous and false makes it synchronous, it should work, check the updated answer. Btw, by default its true so you can remove it from xmlhttp.open(), as in updated answer